# Where can I find Targum Neofiti online?

Tags: hebrew, aramaic

I'm looking for [Targum Neofiti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Neofiti) online in the original Hebrew/Aramaic lettering. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7933713#7933713 _et seq._ regarding scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [it is available online](http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/) at the Hebrew Union College's Jewish Institute of Religion in their [Comprehensive Aramaic Project](http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/). Just click on "Search the CAL textual databases" in the left column. Then go to "Targum Studies Module," then "Browse a Single Targum," and you will see Targum Neofiti. Note that every word is tagged so you can click on it for a lexical analysis. You may need to download special fonts.

Comment: And as a comment since it is technically an advertisement, Logos sells the whole CAL package for only $25 if you use Logos/Libronix (http://www.logos.com/product/7862/the-targums-from-the-files-of-the-comprehensive-aramaic-lexicon-project). It's worth the money IMHO (I don't work for them or get any profit from selling this)

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't find any others via a Google search (including this one), I only knew about this one because I have it in Logos.

Answer (score 5):

The scanned manuscript itself is online at [the Vatican Digital Library (*Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana*)](http://digi.vatlib.it/view/MSS_Neofiti.1).

Comment: Thanks! I expanded this a little to further describe where you found it.